# How can you apply a function repeatedly while updating the input

Tags: r, purrr

I'm searching for a functional programming solution.

How do you repeatedly apply a function to an input, let's say a data-frame, which is updated in each iteration?

**Example**

```
test_df <- tibble(x = c(1, 2, 3, 3),
                  y = c("10_11", "20_21", "30", "31"),
                  z = c("1_2_3_4_5", "1_2_3_4_5", "1", "1_2_3_4_5"))
```

The code below separates the rows by column y and then by column z. Note using `separate_rows(test_df, y, z, sep = "_")` does not work due to `Error: Incompatible lengths: 2, 5`.

```
test_df %>% 
  separate_rows(y, sep = "_") %>%
  separate_rows(z, sep = "_") %>%
  print(n=31)
```

Ideally I would like to only use `separate_rows` once. How can I do this?

A for-loop approach may be:

```
my_vars <- c("y","z")

for(i in 1:length(my_vars)){
  
  test_df <- separate_rows(test_df, my_vars[i], sep = "_")
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Reduce:

```
test_df %>% Reduce(function(...) separate_rows(..., sep = "_"), 2:3, init = .)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 26 x 3
       x y     z    
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 1     1 10    1    
 2     1 10    2    
 3     1 10    3    
 4     1 10    4    
 5     1 10    5    
 6     1 11    1    
 7     1 11    2    
 8     1 11    3    
 9     1 11    4    
10     1 11    5    
# ... with 16 more rows
```

`reduce` from purrr also works (switch the first two args and use .init rather than init for that) but has no real advantage here.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of an caveats of `Reduce` over `reduce`?